# Composer require phpoffice/phpspreadsheet no funciona

Tags: php, composer, phpspreadsheet

Les muestro un problema recurrente al utilizar la libreria de phpoffice/phpspreadsheet al hacer el composer install o composer update marca el siguiente error

Your requirements could not be resolved to an installable set of packages.

Problem 1

```
- Installation request for phpoffice/phpspreadsheet ^1.0 -> satisfiable by phpoffice/phpspreadsheet[1.0.0].
    - phpoffice/phpspreadsheet 1.0.0 requires ext-dom * -> the requested PHP extension dom is missing from your system.
    
    To enable extensions, verify that they are enabled in those .ini files:
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/php.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-mysqlnd.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-opcache.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/10-pdo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-calendar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ctype.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-exif.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-fileinfo.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-ftp.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-gettext.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-iconv.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-json.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mcrypt.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-mysqli.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-pdo_mysql.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-phar.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-posix.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-readline.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-shmop.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sockets.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvmsg.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvsem.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-sysvshm.ini
    - /etc/php/7.0/cli/conf.d/20-tokenizer.ini
    You can also run `php --ini` inside terminal to see which files are used by PHP in CLI mode.
    
    Installation failed, reverting ./composer.json to its original content.
```

Comment: Creo que te hace falta una extensión de PHP que requiere ese paquete, la solución que propones en la respuesta no es la ideal. ¿En que sistema operativo estas?

Comment: En efecto, la solución vendría a estar por el lado de habilitar la librería ext-dom de tu php o en la configuración de tu servidor.